# Why InnoDB storage engine not loading csv files concurrently?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

While loading different csv files to different tables of the same database using innodb storage engine(even tested on aria), csv files seems not to be loaded concurrently. Because, a single csv loading to a table is taking **x** minutes, so i am assuming that loading 3 different csv files to 3 different table should take almost the same(if they are being loaded concurrently), rather it takes **3x** minutes in total. Is there any configuration metrics that I am missing to enable concurrent loading to different tables or is it not supported?

NB: I am loading 3 csv into 3 different tables from 3 different connection to mariadb.

Comment: Can you detail what method(s) are you using to load those csv files?

Comment: I am using the load command from mysql cli: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/foo.csv' INTO TABLE bar FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

Comment: and I have experienced the same timing in case of using 3 different db for 3 different tables, what are the hardware constraints i need to consider if there's any?

Comment: Thank you for explaining that you are using LOAD DATA INFILE. Can you detail what process are you using to call that LOAD DATA.... statements? Are you using bash scripts? I don't understand the process of how you are loading into 3 tables from 3 different connections.

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB?

Comment: How big are the csv files?

Comment: @JesusUzcanga - i am using the LOAD DATA INFILE from 3 different mysql cli from 3 different terminals

Comment: @RickJames -  the csv files are 5gb in size and I am running mariadb server 10.4.8

Comment: Loading into one table?  What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Are there any `UNIQUE` keys in place when you start the `LOADs`?

Comment: (Yes, all these seemingly irrelevant questions _may_ be relevant to the Answer.)

Comment: Can you post the result of SHOW PROCESSLIST; at the time when all 3 scripts are running?

Comment: @RickJames - all tables have the same schema which includes one primary key `bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @RickJames and about uniqueness I did set `unique_checks` to false before loading

Comment: @Jesusuzcanga
`|35 | root | localhost | db_name  | Query   |    6 | Reading file| LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/csv/0.csv' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' |    0.000 |

| 36 | root | localhost | db_name  | Query   |    5 | Reading file| LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/csv/1.csv' INTO TABLE table2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\N' |    0.000 |

|37 | root| localhost | db_name  | Query   |    4 | Reading file| LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/csv/2.csv' INTO TABLE table3 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' |    0.000 |
`

Comment: FYI - i do disable all the keys before loading the csvs(to reduce loading time), i am sure it has nothing to do with the concurrency :)

Comment: Sounds like the disk bandwidth is saturated.